# Using backreferences with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match string with regex with re in python, the pattern I'm looking for is a string composed of:

' *anything* change from ""*something*"" to "*the same thing*". '

The problem is that it is not matching the right case.

Example:

'Value changed from ""Hello"" to "Hello"' --> Here is a match.

'Value changed from ""Hello"" to "World"' --> Not a match but in my case it is matching.

Here is a part of my code:

```
import re

re.compile(r".\* changed from ""(.*)"" to "\\1".*")
match = pattern.search(string)
print(match.string)
```

But when I'm using search function, it matches cases where what's between double quotes isn't equal to what's between single quotes, whereas with "\1" backreferences it's only supposed to match when both are equal.

Is my regex the problem?

Comment: Please [edit] and provide a [mre]. You never define `pattern`, the `\*` is surprising and quotes are not properly escaped. As it's written, I cannot tell whether your problem is caused by those typos. Chances are you just need to remove the last `.*` which will match anything.

Comment: Your code [won't compile](https://ideone.com/OhYydu). Please put the code you are actually using in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you don't need to escape \1 with \\1. Also, you have a couple of another issues in your code:

1. You need to change the quotes or escape the `"` character.
2. You need to use match.group(0) instead of match.string
3. You need to define the string variable.

Here's the corrected code:

```py
import re

string = 'anything changed from ""something"" to "something".'
pattern = re.compile(r'.* changed from ""(.*)"" to "\1".*')
match = pattern.search(string)

if match:
    print(match.group(0))
else:
    print("No match found.")
```